# How Can I Record Karoke while Headphone is plug-in?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, headphones

I want to make a karaoke app and everything is perfect, without headphone plug-in.
[.MixWithOthers, .DefaultToSpeaker])

I want to set it to [.MixWithOthers, .DefaultToHeadPhones])

but there is not any function like that. However mix recording not working when headphone plugged-in.
It's my sample code: https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder/blob/master/AVFoundation%20Recorder/RecorderViewController.swift

func setSessionPlayback() {
        let session:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

```
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not set session category")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    do {
       // try session.setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not make session active")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func setSessionPlayAndRecord()
{
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {

      //  var setCategoryErr: NSError? = nil
      //  var activationErr: NSError? = nil
        //Set the general audio session category
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        var doChangeDefaultRoute: UInt32 = 1
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                                    withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)
        }
        catch let error {

        }

        //Activate the customized audio session
         try session.setActive(true)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not set session category")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    do {
       // try session.setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not make session active")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder/blob/master/AVFoundation%20Recorder/RecorderViewController.swift

Comment: Can not find `.DefaultToHeadPhones`in there.

Comment: There is no function like this:DefaultToHeadPhones.. So i want to know how to record voice and music while headphone is plugged in

Comment: I meant `.DefaultToSpeaker`. Copy & paste error. How I understood, you are setting the audio sessions category to .DefaultToSpeaker, but it does not work for you. So I was lookong for your setup in your code and could not find it. Maybe post relevant code in your question.

Comment: try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                                        withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)

Comment: I used this same code for my app.If u don't mind can you check this link : https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder/blob/master/AVFoundation%20Recorder/RecorderViewController.swift